# Nginx Proxy path to different port with Puppet

Tags: django, nginx, proxy, puppet, nginx-reverse-proxy

If I have an nginx server managed with Puppet, how would I go about using nginx as a proxy for any path that starts with `hostname.com/api`, and forward it to `hostname.com:8000/api`?

Example puppet configuration for server:

```
nginx::resource::server { "${site_name}":
    listen_port     => 80,
    www_root        =>  "/var/www/frontend",
    ssl_redirect    =>  false,
    ssl             =>  true,
    ssl_cert        =>  "/etc/letsencrypt/live/${site_name}/fullchain.pem",
    ssl_key         =>  "/etc/letsencrypt/live/${site_name}/privkey.pem",
    ssl_port        =>  443,    
}
```

I tried this but it doesn't seem to be working (it still loads the react app instead of the api's front-facing template from django)

```
nginx::resource::location{'/api':
    server          =>  $site_name,
    ssl             =>  true,
    proxy           =>  "https://localhost:8000",
}
```

Comment: Is the proxy really on `https://localhost:8000`? Or should it be `http://localhost:8000`?

Comment: @Jon it runs on both http and https, but https is preferred.  I've also tried with http though already.

Comment: What does the server/location config look like in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/sitename.conf? Is the location section turning up in the right places in the server sections?